# Python and geotags

Tags: python, geolocation, tweets

I am trying to accomplish two things:
The first task is simpler than the second,
1. I have a geotag coordinate and a bounding box: (two pairs of coordinates: southwest point of the bounding box and northeast of the bounding box). Is there a good tool that can easily tell me whether a coordinate is located inside this bounding box?
2. I am trying to accomplish the same thing as #1 except instead of checking if a coordinate is inside a bounding box, I am attempting to see if a polygon (four pairs of coordinates) is inside another bounding box.

Would appreciate any pointers to resources! Thanks!